# Executing Batch File Using PHP - Error Occuring

Tags: php, apache, batch-file, runtime-error, execution

**Background:** Using Apache & PHP to create a web program to execute Batch files on another server. I am trying to execute batch files from my regular desktop on a server.

Once I click execute the batch file button on the PHP web page, the following errors appear in the log file.

```
- skip directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\lib\visualvm
- exclude pattern matched=log4j skipping jar file /CTBATCH/fw/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
- exclude pattern matched=log4j skipping jar file /CTBATCH/fw/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar

us.mi.state.dhs.fw.persistence.data.DAOCacheLoader@208a0544.loadDAOPackagesFromJar
(/CTBATCH/fw/lib/poi-3.1-FINAL.jar) failed. Exception was java.io.FileNotFoundException: \CTBATCH\fw\lib\poi-3.1-FINAL.jar 
(The system cannot find the file specified)
```

From what it's output is that a directory is getting skipped, is there anyway to prevent this from occurring? I didn't know if there was any PHP to prevent this, or something I would need to do on a server.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Do you have something to say about the fact that you're getting a **Java** exception?

Comment: I don't know why I am getting a Java exception though. I am using PHP and executing a batch from a server's local C: drive

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a java error, and that the java application can't find the file `/CTBATCH/fw/lib/poi-3.1-FINAL.jar`. Can you verify if it is present?

Comment: Yes all the files are there.  I checked multiple times.

Comment: @JustAnotherUser32 - Then you are executing Java code after all... You've just denied it in another comment.

Comment: This looks like a server with an automated build script that runs from the batch file and involves java. Are you sure that the java file is pointing to the file wich you said to be existing? maybe the `/CTBATCH/fw/lib/poi-3.1-FINAL.jar` is taken from the location of the java file and not your root.